# Pattern needed to emulate subscription service

Tags: java, design-patterns

A publishes something B, C and D objects are interested in knowing, where as E, F and G don't care about it.

When A says something only B,C,D should get this "message".

What design pattern helps best emulate this?

**
How do i use Tibco, without using Tibco?

Comment: What are you trying to use instead? I mean is it a standard Java application, a Web application, a fully fledged J2EE application, etc.

Comment: Standard Java application. Suppose you have a stream of numbers coming your object's way. They are coming up regardless of anything else. At the same time you need to have a number of "listeners" (preferably listeners will et data all at the same time) Depending on the data coming in, some listeners will do something other won't. Support if number if < 10, some listeners will act on it, others will only do somethihng if number if over 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of a normal J2SE application, where the publishers of events and subscribers to events are objects within the same process space, it would be the Observer pattern.

Subscribers would typically inform the publisher that they want to listen to events by calling a specific method such as addListener(), and implementing a specific interface.

So in your example lets say we create an interface NumberEventListener which has one method onNumberEvent(int number)

Your listeners would all implement the NumberEventListener and call addListener() on your publisher object.

Filtering can be applied on either the publisher side or the listener side. So for your implementation you could have your addListener() method be addListener(NumberEventListener listener, int min, int max)  and your listener would only be invoked if the number is between min and max. However this is not a typical implementation because it makes the publisher code more complicated and you can't really be flexible.

In such an example, typically listeners receive all the respective events and discard the ones they're not interested in. It however depends a little on the actual real-life scenario.

Whether the listeners get notified 'at the same time' or sequentially depends on whether the listeners are invoked sequentially or in separate threads by the publisher of the event.

Answer (score 0):

What about Publish - Subscribe message exchange pattern?

Also referred to as Publish / Subscribe Channel in Enterprise Integration Patterns:
http://www.eaipatterns.com/PublishSubscribeChannel.html

In Java, JMS typically provides such a messaging service.

Comment: That is what the pattern is called. Publish / Subscribe. 
It depends now in which context you want to apply this pattern... is it JMS?

Comment: this is not related, I believe Mac is not interested in SOA and enterprise service bus related stuff... he needs a programming design pattern

Comment: @lisak, it doesn't really make any difference whether you're applying this for a small application, or for connecting 2 enterprise applications together. The pattern is that; JMS is just one of the implementations. (I suspect this is just some exam question)

Comment: Yes. Thank you. I am looking to learn if there is a Tibco like pattern i can use. A message (pretend it's multicast on a certain subject) is sent to a number of subscribers. I'd like to make sure those subscribers get the message, while those who do not subscribe don't

Comment: OK. Yes Tibco just implements this generic publish / subscribe concept, which a lot of other systems implement. It is not a proprietary concept. In Java you typically use a JMS provider such as ActiveMQ for this.

Answer (score 0):

Observer pattern.

Alternatively, the Filter chain pattern may apply, as you mention that some of the objects do something based on the contents of the message. It sounds like a filter chain to me.